# Help me understand the translation between homogeneous elliptic functions and modular functions

Tags: modular-forms, elliptic-functions, modular-function

I am trying to follow Iwaniec's book on automorphic forms and am getting hung up on the basic definitions. He seems to construct modular forms from elliptic functions and I can't really follow the reasoning in the details.

Here is the setup: let $f(u;w_1,w_2)$ be a homogeneous elliptic function on the lattice $w_1\mathbb{Z}+w_2\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{C}$. That is $f$ is invariant under translation by this lattice. $u\in\mathbb{C}$. By homogeneous we mean that $f(\lambda u; \lambda w_1, \lambda w_2)= \lambda^{-k}f(u;w_1,w_2)$. Thus we have
$$
    f(u;w_1,w_2) = (w_2)^{-k}f\left(\frac{u}{w_2}; \frac{w_1}{w_2},1\right)
$$
By possibly interchanging $w_1$ and $w_2$ we have $z=w_1/w_2\in\mathbb{H}$ (the upper half plane). Thus we can write 
$$
    f(u;w_1,w_2) = (w_2)^{-k}f\left(\frac{u}{w_2}; \frac{w_1}{w_2}\right)
$$
Where $f(v;z)$ is now a function from $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{H}$. I think maybe I am missing something in this transition because in my head I am just thinking of $f(v;z)$ as shorthand for $f(v;z,1)$. Anyway, by transforming $w_1$ and $w_2$ by a matrix $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ we get a new basis for the same lattice so the $f$ is invariant. Their ratio naturally is transformed by the fractional linear transform $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Now the identity I am struggling with is he says:
"As a function of $z$, $f$ has the property that $$f(\gamma z)=(cz+d)^kf(z)$$"
When I try to work that out I get
$$ f(v;\gamma z)= f\left(v;\frac{az+b}{cz+d},1\right)=(cz+d)^kf(v(cz+d);az+b,cz+d)=(cz+d)^kf(v(cz+d);z,1)$$
This is almost what we want but $v$ has a factor of $(cz+d)$ which seems to contradict the identity $f(\gamma z)=(cz+d)^kf(z)$ if we were to leave $v$ constent unless we choose $v$ to be zero in order to get $f$ as a pure function of $z$. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: If $u=0$ then $v=0$ and $v(cz+d)=0$.

Comment: I understand that but it never said $v$ was assumed to be zero just that we were looking at $f$ as a function of $z$, which I assumed to mean that $v$ was taken to be constant. Do we need to evaluate at $v=0$ in order to use this process?

Comment: It helps to look at important special cases. Read the Wikipedia article [Weierstrass's elliptic funtions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) and the one on [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series).

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with these. I'm not actually sure what you are trying to say. The book basically says that by fixing $u$ (or $v$) the elliptic functions becomes a modular function in $z$. That only seems to be true when $u=0$ to me and that's why I am confused.